# orbits are open in Manifold ? group action on manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I need to show: for a differentiable manifold $M$, and $Aut(M)$ acts on $M$, orbit of a point $a\in M$ is open in $M$, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a local problem:
The key point is to prove that given an open ball in $B\subset \mathbb R^n$  and two points $a,b\in B$, there exists a diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ which is is the identity outside of $B$ and such that $f(a)=b$.
This can be done by constructing a suitable compactly supported (and thus complete) vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ and using the flow it generates.
The details are in Conlon's [*Differentiable Manifolds*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=r2K31Pz5EGcC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false), Lemma 4.1.14, page 134. [And this is your lucky day: Google generously allows you to access that very page and the two following ones.]

As a corollary one immediately obtains that  the automorphism group $Aut(M)$ of a connected manifold $M$ acts transitively on $M$:  the orbit of any point $p \in M$ under $Aut(M)$ is the whole manifold $M$.

**Edit**
In Shastri's [*Element of Differential Topology*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Element_of_Differential_Topology.html?id=DlUVQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) (Corollary 6.3.3, page 166) you will find the following amazing generalization :
Given   a connected manifold $M$ of dimension $\gt 1$ and an integer $k\geq 1$, one can send any $k$-element   subset $\{a_1,...,a_k\}\subset M$ to any  $k$-element subset$\{b_1,...,b_k\}\subset M$  by some  diffeomorphism $f$ of $M$, i.e. $f\in Diff(M)$ satisfies    $f(a_i)=b_i$.

Comment: For the benfit of the OP, it may be worth pointing out that the generalization is not so bad once you already know the trick for $k=1$.  The point is that given any finite number of points on a manifold of dimension 2 or more and two points $p$ and $q$, there is a simple path in the manifold connecting the $p$ and $q$ which misses all the other points.  One now picks a nonzero vector field tangent to the curve and extends it to be $0$ very close to the curve so as to miss the points.  Now just flow.

Comment: Dear @Jason, I really like your invitation to "just flow"  :-)